# How to turn a list into nested dict in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

Need to turn x:

```
X = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D']]
```

Into Y:

```
Y = {'A': {'B': {'C','D'}}}
```

More specifically, I need to create a tree of folders and files from a list of absolute paths, which looks like this:

```
paths = ['xyz/123/file.txt', 'abc/456/otherfile.txt']
```

where, each path is `split("/")`, as per `['A', 'B', 'C']` in the pseudo example.

As this represents files and folders, obviously, on the same level (index of the array) same name strings can't repeat.

Comment: What's this? `{'C','D'}`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with the nested dict?

Comment: What if folder A contains a directory B and also a file X?  How should that be represented?

Comment: Would this be acceptable? `{'A': {'B': {'C': {}, 'D': {}}}}`

Comment: more consistent, Y = {'A': {'B': {'C':{},'D':{}}}}

Comment: Steven, I'm actually trying to create a page with nested ul/li blocks, to render a javascript tree. the way content is saved, though, it's just a list of records, with URL property, that represents an absolute path. I can't just show a flat list, so need to show it as if it's a list of nested directories with files in them.

Comment: Where does the input data come from? If you want to iterate over a directory structure, the normal approach is to just use `os.walk`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
X = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D'],['W','X'],['W','Y','Z']]
d = {}

for path in X:
    current_level = d
    for part in path:
        if part not in current_level:
            current_level[part] = {}
        current_level = current_level[part]
```

This leaves us with d containing `{'A': {'B': {'C': {}, 'D': {}}}, 'W': {'Y': {'Z': {}}, 'X': {}}}`.  Any item containing an empty dictionary is either a file or an empty directory.

Comment: Where does the current_level get added to d?

Comment: @Tyler Hilbert the `current_level` is the `d`! The expression `current_level = d` doesn't make a copy of `d`, it just creates a new reference to `d` named `current_level` ;) The code above wouldn't work if `current_level` was a copy, created like this: `current_level = d[:]` or like this: `current_level = copy.deepcopy(d)`, but since it's not - it merely works!

Comment: @tsveti_iko If it's a reference, why doesn't the line `current_level = current_level[part]` modify only `current_level` and not `d`? I've checked in the debugger, and after this stage (for ex. when we are at the 1st element `A`), we'll get: `current_level = {}` while `d = {'A': {}}`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `{'C', 'D'}` means `set(['C', 'D'])` and your Python version supports `dict comprehension` and `set comprehension`, here's an ugly but working solution:

```
>>> tr = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
>>> {a[0]: {b[1]: {c[2] for c in [y for y in tr if y[1] == b[1]]} for b in [x for x in tr if x[0] == a[0]]} for a in tr}
{1: {2: set([3, 4])}, 5: {6: set([7])}}
```

As for your example:

```
>>> X = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D']]
>>> {a[0]: {b[1]: {c[2] for c in [y for y in X if y[1] == b[1]]} for b in [x for x in X if x[0] == a[0]]} for a in X}
{'A': {'B': set(['C', 'D'])}}
```

But please don't use it in a real-world application :)

**UPDATE:** here's one that works with arbitrary depths:

```
>>> def todict(lst, d=0):
...     print lst, d
...     if d > len(lst):
...         return {}
...     return {a[d]: todict([x for x in X if x[d] == a[d]], d+1) for a in lst}
...
>>> todict(X)
{'A': {'B': {'C': {}, 'D': {}}}}
```

Comment: Also doesn't work for arbitrary depth, which is probably a requirement.

Comment: @[agf](http://stackoverflow.com/users/500584/agf) true - I didn't think that was a requirement, it probably is though. Should I come up with an even more horrible looking one-liner? :)

Comment: Hah, that would just get scary. I think Matt's got the idea -- it has to be done recursively.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical inconsistency in your problem statement.  If you really want
`['xyz/123/file.txt', 'abc/456/otherfile.txt']`

to be changed to
`{'xyz': {'123': 'file.txt}, 'abc': {'456': 'otherfile.txt'}}`

Then you have to answer how a path 'abc.txt' with no leading folder would be inserted into this data structure.  Would the top-level dictionary key be the empty string `''`?

Comment: if there is a file called abc.txt at top level, it'll be a peer with 'xyz' and 'abc', as in {'xyz':{...}, 'abc':{...}, 'abc.txt:{}} . with empty {}, which would indicate it's a leaf

Comment: it doesn't matter if something "looks" like a file or folder. last one will be a file, rest are folders. this is not real file system, btw.

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty close to what you need:

```
def path_to_dict(path):
    parts = path.split('/')

    def pack(parts):
        if len(parts) == 1:
            return parts
        elif len(parts):
            return {parts[0]: pack(parts[1:])}
        return parts

    return pack(parts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    paths = ['xyz/123/file.txt', 'abc/456/otherfile.txt']
    for path in paths:
        print '%s -> %s' % (path, path_to_dict(path))
```

Results in:

```
xyz/123/file.txt -> {'xyz': {'123': ['file.txt']}}
abc/456/otherfile.txt -> {'abc': {'456': ['otherfile.txt']}}
```

Comment: How do you join all the dictionaries, like if you have other paths like `xyz/123/b.a` and `abc/sss/ooo/1.a` that overlap with those?

Comment: What if `'xyz'` contains directories *and* files?

Comment: Matt, I was about to ask same question as agf. This far i got myself. I actually need one dict merged. there will be overlaps, so I can't just replace nodes wholesale, need to actually merge at every level.

Comment: Deeply merge dicts: http://appdelegateinc.com/blog/2011/01/12/merge-deeply-nested-dicts-in-python/

Comment: above link is dead redirects to spam

Answer (score 1):

I got asked about this question on twitter and came up with this slick solution using functional programming which I figure I might as well share here.

```
from functools import reduce
X = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D']]
Y = [reduce(lambda x, y: {y:x}, Y[::-1]) for Y in X]
```

which returns:

```
[{'A': {'B': 'C'}}, {'A': {'B': 'D'}}]
```

as desired.

For the simpler problem where you have one list that you want to represent as a dict with nested keys, this will suffice:

```
from functools import reduce
X = ['A', 'B', 'C']
reduce(lambda x, y: {y:x}, X[::-1])
```

which returns:

```
{'A': {'B': 'C'}}
```

Comment: This does not combine the dicts as desired. Expected output is `Y = {'A': {'B': {'C','D'}}}`

Answer (score 0):

First split keys from values

```
x = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D']]
keys = [tuple(asd[:-1]) for asd in x]
values = [asd[-1] for asd in x]
```

Now use them to populate a `NestedDict`

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

nd = NestedDict()
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    nd[key] = value
```

```
>>> nd
NestedDict({'A': {'B': 'D'}})
>>> nd.to_dict()
{'A': {'B': 'D'}}
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) `pip install ndicts`