# Creating a nested dictionary from list of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to convert below list of lists to a nested dictionary having  `"epc_hlx"` key values to be a `list of dictionary` because it can contain more than one dictionary element like this :

```
      "epc_hlx":[
           {
              "measure":{
              }
           },
           {
              "measure":{
              }
           }
       ]
```

**List:**

```
lst =[['header', 'aircraft'],
['header', 'engine_1'],
['header', 'engine_2'],
['header', 'engine_1', 'epc_hlx'],
['header', 'engine_1', 'epc_hlx', 'measure'],
['header', 'engine_2', 'epc_hlx'],
['header', 'engine_2', 'epc_hlx', 'measure']]
```

Here is the **Expected Output** :

```
{
   "header":{
       "aircraft":{
       },
       "engine1":{
          "epc_hlx":[
               {
                  "measure":{
                  }
               }
           ]
       },
       "engine2":{
          "epc_hlx":[
               {
                  "measure":{
                  }
               }
           ]
       }
    }
}
```

I have tried a few things but nothing works what I want it to be. So I am stuck on this one. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Why does epc_hlx map to a list?

Comment: because i will have several blocs {"measure":{},"ts":{}}

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't see that mentioned in your question, do you?

Comment: why `epc_hlx` has list as values all other have dicts? is there any specific reason?

Comment: yeah because `epc_hlx` will contain 8 dict like this : `{"measure":{},"ts":{}}`

Comment: does this format fixed are changes with the input? I mean any other key should have value as list?

Comment: The input is fix, it will never change and the output dict will always have this structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to Pygirl who posted the previous answer i've finally found the solution.

First thing to do is to modify my input list to :

```
allblocs=[['header', 'aircraft'],
          ['header', 'engine_1', 'epc_hlx', 'measure'],
          ['header', 'engine_2', 'epc_hlx', 'measure']]
```

then i have reused https://stackoverflow.com/a/7654004/6660373 and added a logic for the `epc_hlx` key which gave me this code :

```
dict_header={}    
for blocs in allblocs :
    current_lvl=dict_header
    for bloc in blocs : 
        if bloc not in current_lvl:
           if(bloc == "epc_hlx"):
               current_lvl[bloc]=[]
               current_lvl=current_lvl[bloc]
           elif(bloc == "measure"):
               dict_tmp={}
               dict_tmp[bloc]={}
               current_lvl.append(dict_tmp)
           else:
               current_lvl[bloc]={}
               current_lvl=current_lvl[bloc]
        else:
               current_lvl=current_lvl[bloc]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this answers your completely. But it will give you an idea. You can optimize the solution.

```
li = [['header', 'aircraft'],
['header', 'engine_1'],
['header', 'engine_2'],
['header', 'engine_1', 'epc_hlx'],
['header', 'engine_1', 'epc_hlx', 'measure'],
['header', 'engine_1', 'epc_hlx', 'ts'],
['header', 'engine_2', 'epc_hlx'],
['header', 'engine_2', 'epc_hlx', 'measure'],
['header', 'engine_2', 'epc_hlx', 'ts']]
```

---

1. Making all None values as string. ( I need a list including None to make it equal length that's why used pandas dataframe)

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(li)
df[2] = df[2].astype(str)
df[3] = df[3].astype(str)

lst = df.values
```

---

Borrowing [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7654004/6660373)

```
d = {}

for path in lst:
    current_level = d
    for part in path:
        if part not in current_level:
            current_level[part] = {}
        current_level = current_level[part]
```

---

**Output:**

**d:**

```
{'header': {'aircraft': {'None': {'None': {}}},
  'engine_1': {'None': {'None': {}},
   'epc_hlx': {'None': {}, 'measure': {}, 'ts': {}}},
  'engine_2': {'None': {'None': {}},
   'epc_hlx': {'None': {}, 'measure': {}, 'ts': {}}}}}
```

---

Using regex to clean `'None': {}`:

```
reg = re.compile("'None': {}")

s = str(d)
while (len(re.findall("'None': {}", s))):
    s = re.sub("'None': {}", '', s)
    
s = re.sub("{,", '{', s)
```

---

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(s)
```

---

```
{'header': {'aircraft': {},
  'engine_1': {'epc_hlx': {'measure': {}, 'ts': {}}},
  'engine_2': {'epc_hlx': {'measure': {}, 'ts': {}}}}}
```

Comment: thank you very much i'll search down this way, if i succeed i'll accept your answer :)

Comment: You just need to add the logic for `epc_hlx":[ {...} ]`.

Comment: yeah definitely i think it is the way to go i'm going to lunch and i'll try it after !

Comment: I did not close the question. I cannot delete comments. I did undo your attempt to go against my advice however. And comments get deleted by elected moderators (whcih I am not) if several users think they are rude. Getting answers, even technically correct answers which are helpful to you, is not proof of good questions, many users are to eager to make reputation for keeping the rules in mind. At least 5 people disagree with your opinion that you know how to ask a good question. If three of those have certain privileges your question gets closed until being improved.

Comment: Pygirl, please do you best to help OP with improving the question. I am probably not in a trusted position to do so. And you have some incentive to help them understand. If I see them editing beneficially, I will consider it partially your achievement... ;-) Feel free to let me know when that happens.

Comment: @VincentNAHMIAS Thanks for trying to explain. Please do that within the question itself. Please understand that I actually do not know enough technical detail to judge the answer. I only try to explain meachanisms on StackOverflow. Yes, I did undo your edit, because I can tell when an answer is added to a question and that it should not be. I nevertheless try to help instead of e.g. downvoting (which I did not, I guess you understood that already).

Comment: @Yunnosch i understand and agree what you've done. i was just annoyed because the 3 persons that downvoted the question have done it like 5 mins after i've posted it without trying to understand anything

Comment: Not being able to understand the question kind of supports their decision to close it, "unclear" would even be a dedicated close reason. Not being able to answer and not being able to understand the question are different things. By the way, please be more careful with how you describe users here, especially moderators. You did get a rude comment deleted by one already, didn't you?

Comment: Describing what was attempted would be a good edit, even better with details on how exactly it failed. Please avoid external linking however. Users like info directly in posts.

Comment: sorry but i can't really add what i've tried, it was something like the solution but i have erased and restart multiple times so i lost the track of what i've done.