# String array to nested dictionary Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a begginer in python and I want to make this:

I have a string array I want to make a dictionary with string as keys, but this way:
Transform this:

```
 ['Users', 'ID', 'Age']
```

Into this:

```
{
    'Users': {
        'ID': {
            'Age': None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question may helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653726/how-to-turn-a-list-into-nested-dict-in-python

Comment: I'll watch it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this like so:

```
def tranform_list_to_dict(lst):
    new = {}
    for item in lst[::-1]:
        if not new:
            new[item] = None
        else:
            tmp = {}
            tmp[item] = new.copy()
            new = dict(tmp)
    return new


my_list = ['Users', 'ID', 'Age']
print(tranform_list_to_dict(my_list))
```

Which will produce:

```
{
    "Users": {
        "ID": {
            "Age": None
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may do this

```py
list1 = ['User', 'ID', 'Age']

def transform(alist):
    alist = alist[::-1]
    dic = {alist[0]: None}
    for i in range(len(alist)-1):
        dic = {alist[i]: dic}
    return dic

print(transform(list1))
```